# Android Studio (AS) 4.1 Kotlin Portrait to Landscaoe does not work

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

Having read and tested numerous threads here to this topic (most threads to Java, not to Kotlin), I do not succeed in realizing and do not understand, what i do wrong

This is my Portrait test layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is my Portraittext"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="173dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="344dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I created landscape-xml by "create landscape.." This is the landscape-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is my Portraittext"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="173dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="344dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Kotlin-file is quity simple:

```
package com.example.mytest

import android.content.res.Configuration
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"in portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"in landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Configuration does not change nor does any of the 2 "Toast"-statements fire. (In debug mode the onConfigurationChanged function is not entered

My AndroidManifest.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mytest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTest">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="uiMode|orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This means : quite standard, only extension the

```
    android:configChanges="uiMode|orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
```

I checked several entries in this line with orientation, screenSize, uiMode....., but nothing works. When I force the landscape-mode directly, display goes to landscape as expected.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Try to use `android:screenOrientation="sensor"` on your `Manifest.xml` on your activity

Comment: How can you lmoe the difference if both files are the same? Even the text on the TextView is the same

Answer (score 0):

I want to close my question. It works now without any change on my smartphone, but not in the emulator. May be strange, Sorry